# how do I remove this old track light hanger from junction box?

Tags: light

I need some guidance on how to remove this late 1980's vintage track light mounting strap or hanger (brace?) from the 4" round junction box? It appears to have the two small threaded rods, that the cover plate attached to, go all the way up through the two layers of the metal hanger. There are also two philips head screws holding the "top" of the strap into the j-box just above the lower metal strap. Both appear to be going into some of the plastic 'tabs' of the j-box.

[image: Side view of bracket]
[image: Straight on view of bracket]

Comment: link to photobucket for pictures: http://s747.photobucket.com/user/vthunter/library/Track%20Light%20bracket

Answer (score 3):

If you can push the machine screws up, then you can just spin the bottom half of the bracket and get at the screws that are holding it.

If you can't push them up, grab them with locking pliers (ie, visegrips) and spin them out.

If that doesn't work, use brute force to bend the bottom half of the bracket to give you access to the screws holding the top half. Then you'll be in a better position to assess the hanging machine screws.

oh, and so I can sleep well at night, please put a cap on that black wire... you never know who'll flip a switch on you at the wrong time...

Comment: Thank you for the quick feedback. I surely regret the impression left by my photo; rest assured, the pig-tails were removed and the wire nuts replaced on the ends. I have the power off at the switch and the breaker panel with a homemade lock-out/tag-out (really just a sticky note) on the brkr,.to warn anyone not to flip on. I really appreciate the advice. Thank you!!

Comment: Aloysius, I was able to spin out the two threaded pins (screws) with vise-grips and rotate the bottom half of the bracket, without bending, easy as can be. Removed the two philips screws and ready to go. THANK YOU BOTH!!

Comment: http://i747.photobucket.com/albums/xx117/vthunter/Track%20Light%20bracket/1030161045-01_zpsu8gleg95.jpg

http://i747.photobucket.com/albums/xx117/vthunter/Track%20Light%20bracket/1030161044-00_zps6lgpam1z.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the directions I added to the snip of your photo.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Michael! Sound advice. I'm a bit worried on putting too much pressure on the box. Do you think the ends of the bracket will bend under vise-grips as you and Aloysius instruct? Thx again - no convo intended, just clarifying. Thanks again to both!!